# flutter plugin for running onnx model

Tags: flutter, onnx

My team are developing an app that will involve some on device ML model that are in `onnx` format. Currently we considering Flutter & React Native. I prefer Flutter but couldn't find any plugin that support running on device `onnx` model. in RN we could use `onnx.js` from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no Flutter Plugin to do this but you only need to create one in your project ([link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages)) and take implement [Android version](https://github.com/JDAI-CV/DNNLibrary)  and [iOS version](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-coreml). The plugin will make the wrapper and you can use it in your Flutter code. Depending of the phone OS, flutter will execute Android or iOS code.

Comment: https://github.com/gtbluesky/onnxruntime_flutter and https://github.com/Telosnex/fonnx